# How to compute in-place set difference of two multisets?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two multisets.  I want to remove all elements that occur in the second multiset from the first multiset, *respecting the number of times each element occurs in each multiset*.  For example, If multiset `a` contains `1` five times, and multiset `b` two times, when I compute `a -= b`, only two instances of `1` should be removed from `a`.

Here is some code that accomplishes this:

```
 multiset<int> a;
 multiset<int> b;

 // remove all items that occur in b from a, respecting count ("a -= b")
 for (multiset<int>::iterator i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); i++) {
    if (a.count(*i) < 1) {
       // error 
    }
    // a.erase(*i) would remove ALL elements equal to *i from a, but we 
    // only want to remove one.  a.find(*i) gives an iterator to the first
    // occurrence of *i in a.
    a.erase(a.find(*i));
  }
```

Surely there's a better / more idiomatic way?

Comment: Why are you dereferencing `i` after incrementing it? Likewise iterators are a good reason to start getting used to the good practice of `++i`. Still interresting question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While `std::set_difference` requires you to put the elements into a new set, you can certainly still optimize it by just *moving* the elements from the original set into the new one and swapping both afterwards (Ok, for `int`s moving isn't neccessary, but this way the algorithm keeps flexible and generic).

```
std::multiset<int> c;
std::set_difference(std::make_move_iterator(a.begin()), 
                    std::make_move_iterator(a.end()), 
                    b.begin(), b.end(), 
                    std::inserter(c, c.begin()));
a.swap(c);
```

Not completely in-place, but *nearly* and still quite idiomatic while being linear in complexity (since the `std::insert_iterator` will always provide a proper hint to `std::multiset::insert`).

Comment: Is there any advantage to "moving" when the underlying datatype is just an int?

Comment: @nibot No, but I wrote it more in light of a generic algorithm, didn't really notice that it's just about ints.

Answer (score 2):

See [std::set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/)

It is will work for multisets also.

From the latest draft [n3485](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) 25.4.5.4 [set.diﬀerence]

```
Remarks: If [first1,last1) contains m elements that are equivalent to each other and
[first2, last2) contains n elements that are equivalent to them, the last max(m−n,0)
elements from [first1, last1) shall be copied to the output range.
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in-place?

Comment: @nibot yes, (I think so) I'm trying to figure out a in-place version

Comment: @MikeSeymour It is linear in sizes of the sets, but since sets are associative containers, did you mean logarithmic?

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced: If you want the output to also be a multiset, then you need a logarithmic insertion for each output element, so the overall complexity is `O(N log N)` - slower than linear. It could be linear if you can accept the result in a sequence container instead; but that's even further from the requirement to "remove elements from the first multiset".

Comment: @MikeSeymour But inserting into a `multiset` with a proper hint (which an appropriately set up `std::insert_iterator` will use), should still be constant, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ChristianRau: Yes, after carefully reading the standard I think you're right; it should be linear time, so the only cost compared with an in-place version is the extra memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

Since the containers are ordered, you can iterate through both at once, skipping over values that are only in one set; something like:

```
for (auto i = a.begin, j = b.begin(); i != a.end() && j != b.end();) {
    if (*i < *j) {
        ++i;
    } else if (*j < *i) {
        ++j;
    } else {
        i = a.erase(i);
        ++j;
    }
}
```

This has linear complexity, avoiding the logarithmic-time calls to `count` and `find`.

Alternatively, if you don't mind moving the elements you want to keep into a new map, you could use `std::set_difference`. That probably won't be linear time though, since each element will need to be inserted into the output map.

UPDATE: on further investigation, it seems that `std::set_difference` will be linear, since insertion is required to be linear when given a suitable hint, and `insert_iterator` will provide the correct hint. So that might be regarded as more idiomatic, if you don't mind the extra memory usage of building a new multiset.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised there isn't a standard library function to do this.

Comment: @nibot: The library tends to favour generic algorithms (like `set_difference`) over more container-specific algorithms; but I agree it would be useful to have functions to combine associative containers in-place.